# Determine if Django model has a default

Tags: django, django-models

I want to know if there is a way programmatically of finding the default assigned to a field on any model, I have the model instance and the field names.

In the below model I would have to get the default from u_value, allow_profile and disabled if they are Null to be able to save the data correctly. The Database is Firebird

Eg model:

```
class Fitting(models.Model):
    uuid                         = UUIDField(primary_key=True)
    bought_in_control_panel_file = models.ForeignKey(BoughtInControlPanelFile, db_column='bought_in_control_panel_file_id',null=True, blank=True)
    name                         = models.CharField(_('name'),null=True, blank=False,max_length=255)                           
    code                         = models.CharField(_('Code'),null=True, blank=True,max_length=255)
    fire_rating                  = models.ForeignKey(FireRating, db_column='fire_rating_id',null=True, blank=True)
    u_value                      = models.FloatField(_('U-value'),default=0)
    acoustic_rating              = models.FloatField(_('Acoustic Rating'),default=0)
    allow_profile                = models.BooleanField(default=0)
    disabled                     = models.BooleanField(default=0)
    date_time_updated            = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True, auto_now=True)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

model_field.get_default() returns the default assigned to a model field

Example:

```
model = Polls.objects.all()
for model_field in model:
    print model_field.get_default()
```

Answer (score 0):

Django will automatically save the model instance with default values when you save it and haven't set the required non-null fields.

Doesn't your object saved in DB with default values when they are not set explicitly?

The value for `default` property can be a function which will be called when new object will be saved. You may want to try that too.

Comment: nope it doesn't, because the DB interface is non-standard. i use Firebird.

Comment: @Jharwood you should update your question with such information.